# AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client due to mismatching sample rate

Tags: audio, real-time, low-latency

Does anybody know how to fix this warning message?

> 07-14 10:38:55.411 V/tracker-audiotest(22426): Recording Thread::run(): start audioRecord recording.
>   07-14 10:45:51.490 "W/AudioTrack(  607): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client due to mismatching sample rate (44100 vs 48000)"

When I test the audio latency on Android 4.4, I face a suddenly delay increasing after I saw this warning message. But I don't change the sample rate during the test and the initial setting is in 48kHz. This warning message happen after 7 minutes recording started.

You can test this project on your device if needed. The project is in GitHub:

> https://github.com/garyyu/OpenSL-ES-Android-DelayTest

Answer (score 4):

The **AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST** is denied because you are using a different rate than the one supported in hardware. You need to query the hardware supported sampling rate and record at that rate rather than hard code it to 48kHz.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use Java function interface:

```java
AudioManager myAudioMgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
nativeSampleRate = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
```

to retrieve the hardware default sample rate on your phone, use that to create the player.
Also try to use:

```java
nativeSampleBufSize = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
```

to get default audio buffer size( it is in frames ) and use that for your playback.

You could look at the JNI sample code [audio-echo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/audio-echo) if JNI is ok for you.

Comment: I tried to run your program on my Android-M ( nexus 9 and nexus 5), the raw audio file plays back fine ( I used a music file, so any break would be obvious). your buffer is 480, on my devices, fast audio buffer sizes are:

Comment: 240 frames/buffer, and frequency is 48Khz. I feel the playback is pretty smooth. Android-M has improvement for audio, you could check it out and see if it improves things in your end.

Comment: Looking at the code, in the inner loop, it pulls in recorded audio first, write to the file[copied twice before bits got into the file]; then process the player  by reading in one buffer of audio data, resample it, copy to play buffer [2 copies ]; then mix them and write out to file.   Within one buffer play time, 5 copies, 3 file access, they must finish on time. If it is not finished, player or recorder is starving, will cause glitches. I think it might be better to let player and recorder have double buffer and enqueue a new buffer whenever callback happens. Read file in big chunks too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sample rate at

> frameworks/base/
>   frameworks/av/
>   hardware/libhardware

locations.

default sample rate is 44100 try setting the sample rate you want (your audio files have). it will work.

cheers.