# AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client

Tags: android, audiotrack

I'm getting this AudioTrack warning

```
AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

in my Android app for a button I'm subclassing. I can hear a click when tapping on the button so is this anything to worry about?

Note: I'm not getting the mismatching sample rate message as in this question: [AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client due to mismatching sample rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729488/audiotrack-audio-output-flag-fast-denied-by-client-due-to-mismatching-sample-ra)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Most likely, the tap sound got a `AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST` in order to use low-latency playback if possible, but the `AudioTrack` class considered the track settings to be incompatible with the low-latency audio output, so the flag got removed and the track got treated as if the flag hadn't been set to begin with. So I wouldn't consider this to be something to worry about.

As for the reason why the flag got denied; I'd still say that the most probable reason is a sample rate mismatch. The log in the question you linked to appears to have been added in [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/4361749d74113069aafb0620a1189404205c58d0%5E1..4361749d74113069aafb0620a1189404205c58d0/) to the AOSP. But if we look at [the master branch of the code base used on many Qualcomm-based devices](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n964) we see that it still has the `"AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client"` log in the case were there was a sample rate mismatch. Which logs you get depends on the exact implemetation running on your device (i.e. which device and Android version you're running).

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thanks.

Comment: The log in that file is different, unless it was changed since you read it ("AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer %d, track %u Hz, output %u Hz").  The simple "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client" message seems to be something else (which I'm still trying to track down): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.2.2_r1/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp#773

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the sample rate at
"frameworks/base/
frameworks/av/
hardware/libhardware" locations.

default sample rate is 44100 try setting the sample rate you want (your audio files have).
it will work.

cheers.

Comment: But sounds will take twice more space that way.

Answer (score -6):

I had the same problem, my problem was caused because I forgotten type activity define in manifest file. such as : `activity android:name=".NFCReaderActivity"`