# MediaPlayer can't play music from SD Storage

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard

I'm trying to play music from a ListView (which takes data from a file path). But everytime i click, it gets an error like this:

> 09-14 09:58:42.996    1229-1276/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client

Even I use file path directly, it still doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyOwnMusicFolder");
private File[] files;

public void playSong(int position){   //position of the item in the ListView
    if(mMediaPlayer !=null) {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        try {


            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(dir + File.separator + files[position].getName());
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
       catch (IOException e){
    //something...
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: I'm using Android Studio + Android Studio Emulator

Edit 2: my mp3 files are completely normal

Comment: do you have read permissions?

Comment: @MetaSnarf yes, i do have it

Comment: what part of your code do you get the error? Please post your stack trace

Comment: @MetaSnarf when i click at the item (which means the song), the song can't play, and get the error "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client".         


If I knew what part, I'd not ask this question !

Answer (score 0):

"Most likely, the tap sound got a AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST in order to use low-latency playback if possible, but the AudioTrack class considered the track settings to be incompatible with the low-latency audio output, so the flag got removed and the track got treated as if the flag hadn't been set to begin with. So I wouldn't consider this to be something to worry about.

As for the reason why the flag got denied; I'd still say that the most probable reason is a sample rate mismatch. The log in the question you linked to appears to have been added in this commit to the AOSP. But if we look at [the master branch of the code base used on many Qualcomm-based devices](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n964) we see that it still has the "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client" log in the case were there was a sample rate mismatch. Which logs you get depends on the exact implemetation running on your device (i.e. which device and Android version you're running)."

Answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820211/audio-output-flag-fast-denied-by-client). Credits to Michael

This most like is caused by mismatch on the sample rate and it should not affect the program runtime IF it is running on an actual device. [Ref:](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/im-getting-a-audiooutputflagfast-denied-by-client-error-whenever-i-tap-on-the-hourly-forecast-button-stormy)

Comment: so...all i need to do is run it on an actual device ?