# AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server warning in Android O

Tags: android, android-notifications

Currently, I am working with `Android O` in one of our application, I'm receiving the notification but there is no beeper sound associated with it. I have set the sound to the notification channel but no results. I'm receiving a warning `AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST` denied by the server. Apart, from this no errors. Can someone please evaluate this?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820211/audio-output-flag-fast-denied-by-client

Answer (score 1):

The [design documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/latency/design) describes a difference between the client level denying the request and the server (AudioFlinger) denying the request for a "fast track".  If the client (C++ implementation library that you call) passes on the request, it may also be denied at the server level.  The page describes the conditions required to create a "fast track" and one of these is probably not met in your case.

I also have this error and yet the system allocates a "normal track" and the audio flows, just with too much latency.  I wish I could get more information on why it has been denied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer the link was very much useful.