# PLaying sound on smarteyeglasses causes warning

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

I am following the guide here https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/use-bluetooth-for-audio-io/

When I play a raw mp3 on Smarteyeglasses using the code

```
SoundPool mSoundPool  = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL, 0);
// Use the play() method to request for playback of an audio file.
int soundId = mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.cannotregisterreceiver, 1);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Playing sound");
            int returnValue = soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);              
            Log.d(TAG, "Playing sound " + returnValue);
        }
});
```

I get a warning saying `AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client` and the audio is not played

Any ideas why?

Comment: Same problem with MediaPlayer. I get instead IOException prepare failed

Comment: This problem is usually caused when smartphone does not support sample rate of the file. What phone are you using? Can you also share the sample rate information of the mp3 file?

Thanks,

Comment: A similar case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729488/audiotrack-audio-output-flag-fast-denied-by-client-due-to-mismatching-sample-ra